# Completely delete and make again superblock on USB ext4 partition

Tags: linux, hard-drive, usb, partitioning

I have a 64GB usb key with one *ext4* partition (and gpt partition table) and a broken superblock. I don't have any data to save, I just want to 
clear up it so it can be used again.

The first thing I tried was to just create a new partition table with no partitions, but nothing worked. I tried with different devices and programs, KDE partition manager and Windows formatting option. The programs just get stuck, even just by simply trying to read the USB key, and make the entire OS crash if I try to close the program.

So the first thing I tried was the command:

```
sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sdX1 status=progress  (with x as my partition)
```

`status=progress` Shows some output, here it is:

```
1630437888 bytes (1,6 GB, 1,5 GiB) copied, 32,095 s, 50,8 MB/s
```

Then the program blocks and the only way to stop it is either reboot or pull the USB key out. Executing the command again gives the same result.

EDIT:I tried like 5 or 6 times this method yesterday, now I did it again and it completes, but the broken ext4 partition is still broken and can't be read.

Here is the output of sudo `sudo fdisk -l` (I removed the output of the other disks):

```
Disk /dev/sdc: 59,6 GiB, 64019759104 bytes, 125038592 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: 356FC086-EAFC-4CC2-95A5-C3D82600BE15

Device       Start      End   Sectors  Size Type
/dev/sdc1    2048 125037204 125035157 59,6G Linux filesystem
```

Now I googled how to repair a broken superblock, with different keywords on how to format a partition and other things, but **NOTHING** works. Here are all my attempts (I may have forgotten some):

Most of guides and answers say to just copy the backup of a good superblock and replace it on the bad superblock. You can get a list of backups with:

```
sudo mke2fs -n /dev/sdc1
```

Which gives as output (I translated it from Italian):

```
Creation of file system with 1507955 4k blocks and 377504 inode
File system label=0cb1b2b6-cc59-4a5b-9450-4a1f4a68768d
Backup of the superblock saved in blocks: 
    32768, 98304, 163840, 229376, 294912, 819200, 884736
```

Then I tried to recover a backup superblock with the command `sudo e2fsck -b block_number /dev/sdc1`, which gives as output, for **EVERY SINGLE BLOCK NUMBER**:

```
e2fsck 1.42.13 (17-May-2015)
Super-blocco needs_recovery flag is clear, but journal has data.
Flag di recupero non impostato nel super-blocco di backup, eseguo journal comunque.
MintFormi: ripristino del journal
Super-blocco needs_recovery flag is clear, but journal has data.
Flag di recupero non impostato nel super-blocco di backup, eseguo 
journal comunque.
Super-blocco needs_recovery flag is clear, but journal has data.
Flag di recupero non impostato nel super-blocco di backup, eseguo journal comunque.
e2fsck: impossibile impostarei i flag del superblocco a MintFormi


MintFormi: ***** THE FILE SYSTEM HAS BEEN MODIFIED *****

MintFormi: ********** WARNING: file system still contains errors ************
```

I also tried `fsck.ext4 -p -b block_number -B 4096 /dev/sdX1`, which has the same output.
Also tried `sudo testdisk`, but it suggested to use the commands above to repair the broken superblock.
I don't know what else I can try. As I already said, I don't have any data to save on it, I was just trying to install a live usb system on it. The only thing I really need is a command to just reset every single bit in that USB key, and the job should be done right?

EDIT:
After trying the above commands again, both fsck and e2fsck give the following output:

```
fsck.ext4: Attempt to read block from filesystem resulted in short read in opening /dev/sdc1
Is it possible this is a partition of 0 dimension?
```

Edit: 
I tried to connect on the same USB port to another hard disk. Now also this hard disk says it has got a broken superblock. Fortunately testdisk exists, otherwise I would be dead.

Comment: did you try to merely re-create the filesystem using "sudo mke2fs /dev/sdc1" ?

Comment: Well I tried with KDE partition manager, just tried with your command and it gets stuck at inode 338/447.

Comment: quite strange. some hardware issue maybe?

Comment: Yes probably an hardware issue, as you can see in my last lines (the second edit) after connecting an external hard disk I had the same error. But after a reboot the hard disk worked again, meanwhile the usb key doens't work anymore. Do you know if there is a way to check?

Comment: Hardware issue .? No , I too have the same issue with my SD card , I used exactly the same command and wiped out my data. Please can anyone suggest a anwser ? . And i have also lost the backup of superblock .....